# How to avoid datetime.strptime() non-matching ValueError?

Tags: python, date, datetime

How exactly do I format this date?

```
date = '2020-09-05 15:00:1605 Sep 2020, 15:00 '
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d,  %H:%M:%S')
```

When I do this, I get an error. What am I doing wrong? How should my date variable be formatted? I think the millisecond is off plus How do I format `Sep 2020, 15:00`?

The error I get is

```
ValueError: time data '2020-09-05 15:00:1605 Sep 2020, 15:00 ' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d,  %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: Hi Matt! Which error are you getting? Can you please edit your question to include it?

Comment: just did now thanks

Comment: do you always receive data in a format like this? if you only want the "2020-09-05 15:00:1605" part, I'd suggest to do a `regex` matching first before feeding into strptime. The [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821140/10197418) to slice the string at a fixed index seems pretty unflexible to me (and thus maybe also error-prone).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your date variable do not match for format you are passing to `datetime.strptime`.

The following works:

```py
date = '2020-09-05 15:00:1605 Sep 2020, 15:00 '
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date[ : 19 ], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Note that I removed the `05 Sep 2020, 15:00`  by slicing the `date` variable and changed the date format string a little bit to remove the comma and the double space after it.

Now it works fine:

```
>>> datetime_object
datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 5, 15, 0, 16)
```

Comment: Thank you I guess the problem is that I am handling a lot of data and I cannot change the 15:00:1605. I need to convert that to miliseconds??

Comment: the data I am querying may change but in general it will be in this format 15:00:1605

Comment: If the input date always have the same size, you can slice it to include only the initial fragment, such as `date[ : 19]`. If that helps you, I can edit my answer to include it.

Comment: oh okay so is it datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')[:19] ?

Comment: I just updated my answer to include the slice operation. In that case, you should slice the `date` variable before passing it to the `datetime.strptime` function.

Comment: THANK YOU! but now I get this error  Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable

Comment: I'm glad to help :). You are probably trying to serialize the `datetime.datetime` object as json, which is not supported by the default `json` module. I recommend opening another question on this matter, since it falls out of scope here. Also, if my answer helps you, feel free to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to check the input with a `regex` and parse to datetime with `fromisoformat` if there is a match.

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

s = '2020-09-05 15:00:1605 Sep 2020, 15:00 '

 # assuming you need this often, run a compile
p = re.compile('[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}\ [0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2}')
m = re.search(p, s)

if m:
    print(repr(datetime.fromisoformat(m.group(0))))
    
# datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 5, 15, 0, 16)
```